# Need help understanding methods and exceptions [objectiveC]

Tags: objective-c

I'm having issues with one of the practise questions given by my teacher. I don't even understand what the question is asking, so any help would be appreciated.

"To practise methods and classes write a class with a method that throws an exception. Write another method for the class that invokes the previous method, catches and handles the exception. Test your code using a main function."

The only thing I understand is testing it with the main function. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but we're not the... Most friendly site towards homework questions.  Perhaps you could read about [NSException](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or [assertions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert).

Comment: Do you have a textbook? Have the lectures covered exception handling? Does your professor have office hours?

Comment: This is more appropriate for chat or a forum. See these docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is a method that contains a try/catch statement

```
@try {
    //do something
}
@catch (NSException *exception){
   //do something if the code in the try failed

   //OR
   @throw exception; //this will make the method called "above" this method handle the exception (eg a method calling another method, that fails, passes the exception back to the top level one)
}
```